# A specific word to describe inverse relationships

Tags: terminology

Is there a word that encapsulates inverse relationships? It's probably a theistic term. Something that could describe a profound nature like near and far or without and within.

Edit: The word I'm looking for describes a nature that is, paradoxical? The only example I can readily think of is God. God is described as both near and far, a presence both without and within. Is their a word that describes this contrasting nature?

--> God is _______.

Dichotomy is on the right track, but not quite it.

Comment: They have high negative correlation?  They are antonyms? They are inverses? I think you need to give us the exact relationship(s) you're thinking about.

Comment: The *growing away from each other* idea is captured by *dichotomous*, but it isn't confined to inverse relationships. And it seems like it may be too mundane for what you want.

Comment: What would be wrong with "opposite" or even "inverse" itself, please?

If you'd posted some research, or even personal speculation, what examples might we have to work with?

Comment: God could be ***omnipresent*** which implicitly covers near/far, without/within- but not it’s not clear whether you want to say it can’t be classified that way or that it had an equal footing in both camps.

Comment: No, it isn't omnipresent either.  The word describes the almost oxymoronic nature of the two extremes. So while it could be used to describe something like girly man, or little big the word encompasses two inverse extremes and further adds a layer of profoundity. Sorry if I'm being vague, I feel like I used to know it, and it's just slipped away from me. But after reading all of these excellent responses I'm beginning to wonder...

Comment: The term 'mystery' is used to describe concepts / realities beyond the human mind (such as the Tri-unity). The 'doctrine of tensions' is the study of paradoxical, seemingly conflicting, truths. [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/antinomy) has: << **antinomy**: in philosophy, contradiction, real or apparent, between two principles or conclusions, both of which seem equally justified ... nearly synonymous with the term 'paradox' >>

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think that *paradoxical* itself might make sense, except what you're looking for is a specific sense of the word.

God is [**self-contradictory**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-contradictory):

> : consisting of two contradictory members or parts

This is assuming that you mean near and far or within and without to be mutually exclusive—which is part of the definition of [dichotomy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dichotomy).

---

Alternatively, God (in one sense) could be considered to be [**dialectical**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dialectical):

> **1** *philosophy*
>   **a** : of, relating to, or in accordance with dialectic · *dialectical* method · *dialectical* reasoning

[Dialectic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dialect):

> **5 a** : any systematic reasoning, exposition . . . or argument that juxtaposes opposed or contradictory ideas and usually seeks to resolve their conflict : a method of examining and discussing opposing ideas in order to find the truth

Comment: 'Dialectic' has swayed me to upvote, though God is not self-contradictory but paradoxical (ie He only appears self-contradictory to those without the mental capabilities to grasp all aspects of truth). As a gifted speaker once explained: "Of course, you're on a loser with theology [proper] – it's man trying to understand God".